# Circular Array not working after modifiyng cube in 2.81

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make this circular array of cubes that would sit on a UFO so it's sitting on an angle. It's working when I make a regular circular array of unmodified cubes, but as soon as I modify the cube to make the array with, it goes crazy, the locations are all off.I did set the cursor to the UFO's origin and the cube's origin to the cursor.Basically I am trying to make a circular array to use as a Boolean to cut some holes in the UFO.

Setting up for the array
[image: Setting up for the array]

Making the array with simple cubes
[image: Making the array with simple cubes]

When I modify the cube and make the array
[image]

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ7Kf.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ7Kf.jpg) After applying the size and rotation it worked with no problems /Thank you Robin.

Answer (score 3):

First shot:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > Apply the scale of the cube. (bake the scale into the mesh). Each iteration of the array will inherit the transform of the original, and apply it again, recursively. You want that for the rotation, but not the scale.

Comment: Thank you Robin. It Worked. I applied the size and rotation. Thank you again.